# WIX "The system cannot find the file" when it is really there

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

So I am attempting to build a Wix installer.  And I am getting the following error.

```
Error   1   The system cannot find the file 'C:\Plastic\W2\AktionTLW2\AktionTLW2\bin\Debug\Templates\Federal.xml)'.
```

The relevant code is

```
<File Source="$(var.AktionTLW2.TargetDir)Templates\Federal.xml)"  />
```

When I change that to an explicit path, it does not give me an error:

```
<File Source="C:\Plastic\W2\AktionTLW2\AktionTLW2\bin\Debug\Templates\Federal.xml"/>
```

Notice the explicit path and the path in the error message are the same path.  So why doesn't the first work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres a parenthesis at the end of the path of the error message.. Maybe that's what caused the error have a look at your config file and remove the bracket.

Comment: Rachel you rock.  I have compared line by line by line and missed that close parenthesis. You are my hero of the day :)